# How do I replace custom BBCode style tag with a hyperlink

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode

I've got a bunch of text which can contain custom tags in this format:

```
[MYLINK ID="1234" URL="http://mywebsite.com" TEXT="Website link"]
```

The text can contain multiple links.  What I'm trying to do is to translate the tags to normal html links and grab the IDs in C# code.  The resulting replaced tag should be in this format:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com?id=1234">Website link</a>
```

So to clarify, if I had the following chunk of text:

```
This is a test [MYLINK ID="1234" URL="http://mywebsite.com" TEXT="website link"] with some more text and [MYLINK ID="2345" URL="http://mywebsite2.com" TEXT="another link"] here too.
```

It should translate to this:

```
This is a test <a href="http://mywebsite.com?id=1234">website link</a> with some more text and <a href="http://mywebsite2.com?id=2345">another link</a> here too.
```

EDIT: Been faffing with Regex for the last couple of hours and have managed to get the following to match the tag but don't know what to do next...

```
\[MYLINK ID=\"(.*?)\" URL=\"(.*?)\" TEXT=\"(.*?)\"\]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attributes always in the order you showed, you can use

```cs
var text = "[MYLINK ID=\"1234\" URL=\"http://mywebsite.com\" TEXT=\"Website link\"]";
var pattern = "\\[MYLINK\\s+ID=\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+URL=\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+TEXT=\"([^\"]*)\"]";
var replacement = "<a href=\"$2?id=$1\">$3</a>";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// => <a href="http://mywebsite.com?id=1234">Website link</a>
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5BMYLINK%5Cs%2BID%3D%5C%22%28%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%29%5C%22%5Cs%2BURL%3D%5C%22%28%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%29%5C%22%5Cs%2BTEXT%3D%5C%22%28%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*%29%5C%22%5D&i=%5BMYLINK%20ID%3D%221234%22%20URL%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%22%20TEXT%3D%22Website%20link%22%5D&r=%3Ca%20href%3D%22%242%3Fid%3D%241%22%3E%243%3C%2Fa%3E) and the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/AqPlEa).

*Details*:

- `\[MYLINK` - `[MYLINK` text
- `\s+` - any one or more whitespaces
- `ID=\"` - `ID="` text
- `([^\"]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\"\s+URL=\"` - `"`, one or more whitespaces, `URL="` text
- `([^\"]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\"\s+TEXT=\"` - `"`, one or more whitespaces, `TEXT="` text
- `([^\"]*)` - Group 3 (`$3`): zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\"]` - `"]` text.

Comment: Wasn't aware of  \s+ for whitespaces!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I literally just got it as you were posting, doing something very similar...

```
string pattern = @"\[MYLINK ID=\""(.*?)\"" URL=\""(.*?)\"" TEXT=\""(.*?)\""\]";
text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, x => $"<a href='{x.Groups[2].Value}?id={x.Groups[1].Value}'>{x.Groups[3].Value}</a>");
```